# SQOOP export command VS DB2 LOAD CLIENT

Tags: performance, hadoop, db2, hive, dblink

I have a scenario where I have copy data from hive to db2. There are two ways I can implement this. One is using sqoop export command and another is db2 load client. I need to know which is best approach with respect to performance. Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop can be used to transfer large sized data file in HDFS concurrently (using mappers) to db2. I have no idea about db2 load client.

Comment: Yeah, so the uploads to DB2 kind of becomes faster, since mappers run parallely.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.. If using DB2 LUW, with the sqoop connector it can be faster depending on how many clusters you have available (mappers).  DB2 Load (at least in the z world) can do parrallel loading so depending on how many cp's on the database system, that could be faster.  So I guess it depends on your environment (the database system vs the hadoop cluster).